# Relative Path Connection String with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, connection-string, relative-path

I'm using the following code to create the `Session Factory` with NHibernate. I'd like to specify this path with a relative path instead so that when my teammates and I merge our branches, we don't have to keep fixing the connection string. How can I accomplish this?

```
private static void InitializeSessionFactory(bool deleteSchemaOnClosing = false, bool regenerateSchemaOnOpening = false)
{
_sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                  .ConnectionString(
                      @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=""C:\MyProject\MyProjectCore\Fluent NHibernate\CoreDatabase.mdf"";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
                  .ShowSql()
    )
    .Mappings(m =>
              m.FluentMappings
                  .AddFromAssemblyOf<User>())
    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
                                    .Create(deleteSchemaOnClosing,regenerateSchemaOnOpening))
    .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

My `app.config` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="CoreDatabase.Properties.Settings.CoreDatabaseConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CoreDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="Fluent_NHibernate.Properties.Settings.CoreDatabaseConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CoreDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/></startup></configuration>
```

Thanks you!

Comment: can you add the path to the .config file and get it using "{0}", ConfigFile Key ..? you can use {0} params as well in the .config file also to read the value dynamically that way the change will only happen in 1 location instead of having to keep recompiling the code every time that value needs to change

Comment: Hi DJ KRAZE, can you please dumb it down for me? I am a complete rookie at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at SqlConnectionStringBuilder, you could do something like:

```
var rawStr = Settings.CoreDatabaseConnectionString.ConnectionString;
// retrieve the original connection string from config file

var conBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(rawStr);
conBuilder.AttachDBFilename = Path.GetFullPath(
    Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "CoreDatabase.mdf"));
// if you're doing this in a web environment, swap Environment.CurrentDirectory 
// for HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath

_sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                  .ConnectionString(conBuilder.ToString())
                  .ShowSql()
    )
// rest of your configuration...
```

Comment: Hi Martin! Thanks for the response. I'm trying to figure out how to use `var rawStr = Settings.CoreDatabaseConnectionString.ConnectionString;` but it is not working. I also tried `var rawStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Fluent_NHibernate.Properties.Settings.CoreDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;` which doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: From your app.config file it looks like you should have a class called settings which wraps access to the connection strings.  If not,  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Fluent_NHibernate.Properties.Settings.Co‌​reDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString should work - what error do you get if you do this?

Comment: Trying to extract the connection string with "Fluent_Nhibernate.Properies..." yields a null reference error for me. This is due to the fact that the ConfigurationManager contains two strings, one of which is `{data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true}` and the other is `null`

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/416198/How-to-get-Connection-String-from-App-Config-in-cs for how to get the connection string from your app.config file

Comment: Ah, I found the issue. The app.config file was in the project that had the database. This is all good and fine but I need to also have the same information in the app.config file of the project I am working in. Silly me. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

as an Example you could follow something like this .. 
this would be a way of Saving values to a .Config file but just to give you an example of how Parameters can be used inside of a .Config file take a look at this.

I will also append to my answer an easier way if you truly need an example

```
//Add config like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>

  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>


 Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings(
                                                          "MyConnectionString",
                                                          String.Format("DataSource={0};InitialCatalog={1};IntegratedSecurity={2}",
                                                                         "testing", "testing2", "Testing6")));
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
            MessageBox.Show(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString)
```

Take a look at how to read from Config File as well try out the sample code on the link and step thru the code it will be an awesome learning experience...
[How to read Application Settings from .Config file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Hey DJ KRAZE, would you be able to help me with an example?

Comment: I gave you an example what are you having issues with.. please paste or show code where you are implementing the Params example thanks